# Norm preserving Matrix properties

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Norm-2 preserving can be done using unitary/orthogonal matrix: $A^*A = I => ||Ax|| = ||x||$

What is the matrix other than identity matrix that can preserve other norms ( norm-1, norm-inf) ?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? All possible pairs (matrix, norm preserved by it)?

Answer (score 1):

My intuition says that you are limited to +1 or -1 on the diagonal if it should hold for all x and all norms.

General rotations won't survive taxi distance or max in $R^2$ already.

Comment: It is going to include all permutation matrices as well.